# Problema com o atributo "match" de um campo de texto

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estou usando o atributo `match` de um `<p:password/>`, mas ele não funciona apropriadamente.

```xhtml
<p:password id="senha"/>
<p:password match="senha"/>
```

Quando eu envio o formulário via *commandButton*, uma mensagem de erro surge, dizendo que as senhas não combinam, mesmo eu tendo colocado os caracteres iguais.
Como posso resolvê-lo?

Comment: Você recebe os valores na sua Controller, se recebe poderia postar o método que recebe? Já tentou ver se estão vindo nulo? Poderia postar qual erro dá?

Comment: Não recebo nada no controle, quero dizer, não atribuo nenhum atributo ao `p:password` com o *match*. O PrimeFaces não faz isso automaticamente?

Comment: Não, ele não faz, você tem que mandar para sua Controller, veja [aqui](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml), você precisa setar no campo value sua ManagedBean.Password. Considerando "Password" um atributo

Comment: Ah, só para confirmar: os dois usam o mesmo atributo como valor?

Comment: Sim, de uma lida no artigo em que eu comentei, é sempre bom voce ler o ShowCase do PrimeFaces

Answer (score 1):

Segue o exemplo @Patrick

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="matchGrid" cellpadding="5">                   
    <h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password 1: *" />
    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{passwordView.password5}" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" required="true" />

    <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Password 2: *" />
    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{passwordView.password5}" label="Password 2" required="true" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Na verdade a propria API verifica com o `match` o que falta no seu código é o atributo que a senha receberá em sua `View`

Comment: Não funcionou, continua a dar o mesmo erro.

Comment: como está o codigo na sua View e no seu XHTML?